# Formatting out of a jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, format, datepicker

I'm having a problem trying to format the output on the jQuery UI datepicker.

I want the dateformat to be the 'ISO 8601' format, like explained here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

This is what my code looks like:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl']);
$('.datepicker').datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your option setter format is just a bit off, try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
```

[See the options pane on that page for how to set each one in this way](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

when doing it globally before creating a picker, do this:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl']); 
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
//Later..
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Also, make sure to include your regional file, or the `$.datepicker.regional['nl']` doesn't mean anything, this needs to be included before trying to setDefaults to your regional: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/

Comment: I thried that , It's not working. I'm following this step:
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', {dateFormat: $(this).val()});
in the source view of the demo link I gave you

Comment: @Sam - is the datepicker open when doing this?  This only affects a created datepicker on `$('.datepicker')`, if you're doing this on page init before creating one, do: `$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });` (after your current setDefaults call)

Comment: k thx! This did it :

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl']);
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$('.datepicker').datepicker();

Comment: @Sam - Excellent, +1 and welcome to SO, you can now vote on things :)  I'll edit this answer to the next person having your problem find the solution faster

Comment: got it! Best to mention in your final answer that people still have to include the regional files for datepicker. Located here: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/

Comment: @Sam - Make sure you're including the regional file for nl before running that: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js

Answer (score 7):

```
$( "#end_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

is what works for me

Comment: Also worked for me (jQuery 1.8.2 / UI 1.9.1) - using a datepicker class instead of an ID

Comment: This is a great answer because I was using the calendar icon, passing other options and this answer handles that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a shorter way:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.extend(
    $.datepicker.regional['nl'],
    {
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    }
));
```